# Trying to create a program to find the height of a non binary tree. Ending up with a really long loop and no answer

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, recursion, tree

C++

Hello. I am trying to find the height of a tree. The tree may or may not be binary. The input format is

1. Number of nodes
2. Parent of each node

eg: 5

4 -1 4 1 1

Intended Result: 3

Each integer refers to the array location of its position's parent node. For example, value at 0 has the value 4, meaning that its parent is value at 4, whose value is 1, meaning its parent is value at 1, whose value is (-1), meaning that it is the root of the tree.

The end result is that somehow my program malfunctions when the height(Nod*) function begins, and it prints no answer at all despite a clear cout at the end.

I have tried a lot of stuff, but at this point I really cannot see what went wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Nod
{
    public: Nod* parent;
    Nod* child[];
};

int height(Nod* root)
{
    int i, Q, MAX=0;
    if(root->child[0]==NULL)
        return 1;
    else
        for(i=0; root->child[i]!=NULL; i++)
    {
        Q=height(root->child[i]+1);
        if(MAX<Q)
            MAX=Q;
    }
        return MAX;
}
int main()
{
    int i, j, k, n;
    Nod* root=NULL;
    cin>>n;
    int A[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin>>A[i];

    Nod no[n];

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        k=0;
        if(A[i]==-1)
        {
         no[i].parent=NULL;
         root=&no[i];
        }
        else
            no[i].parent=&no[A[A[i]]];
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(A[j]==i)
                no[i].child[k++]=&no[j];
        }
        no[i].child[k]=NULL;
    }

    int ht=height(root);
    cout<<endl<<ht;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2 prolems: (1) `Nod* child[];` `warning: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'child' [-Wpedantic]` and (2) you never allocate any memory for the `child` array.  So Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaking what type of data Nod[] is. It is a pointer to Nod type, meaning you need to allocate it. Further, accessing out of range on such a type will not return NULL, it will segfault. This behavior exits your program quietly, without displaying any indication of the exit. For your purposes I would recommend looking into   [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) as opposed to static arrays. The rest of your method looks good.

You should look into .size() to test for emptiness and .push_back()